# How to use "values-v11" folder with Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, themes, xamarin.android

[The android doc here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#SelectATheme) states that I can target Api Level 8+ devices and still specify that I want to use the Holo theme for devices that are API Level 11+. I should be able to do this using two themes.xml files :

- One would go in /Resources/values for devices of API Level 8, 9 and 10
- One would go in /Resources/values-v11 for devices with API Levels 11+

In a Xamarin.Android project, using Xamarin Studio it doesn't look like it's working, I get a compile time error :

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo'.
```

Am I doing something wrong here ? Is there a workaround ?

Comment: What is your project target?

Comment: @RaghavSood it's on Automatic

Comment: @RaghavSood OK got it. I've increased the Target API Level and now it's working as expected. Do you want to post an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theme.Holo is only available on API 11 and above.

If your project target is set to automatic, the system will build against the minimum level required (I think).

Try explicitly setting it to a higher API version.

Comment: You're right. From the docs : targetSdkVersion : An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)